# How to determine the material of a face without rendered display?

Tags: materials

I'm working with solids that could have several materials on different faces. Because the model is quite big, I'm used to work on wireframe display.

Sometimes I need to change face materials and it seems there is no way to tell which material the face is wearing, unless, it seems to me, to work on rendered display. This is inconvenient because as I explained before, the model is complex and rendered view tend to slow the work flow and, more important, sometimes different material could have same color!

I'm quite new to blender and I will not be surprised to have missed some basic tools. Please suggest me some ways to work with meshes with several materials and be able to easily detect them, thank you for your time.

Comment: Whenever you select a single face, the corresponding material should highlight in the material slot list

Comment: same as he said, also you can color materials in solid mode as well, just go down in material settings and find **Vieport Display**, there is a color input that is visible only in solid mode

Comment: That's the kind of reasons why we need the random color display to have different modes including "per material" instead of "per objects".

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos In Blender 2.8 the highlighted material in the slot do not change if I select a different face. Maybe new versions have this feature?